# Android Studio "calculate" I created won't click or work at all

Tags: java, android

MainActivty.java file which allows user to input data into fields, and then they hit 1 button "calculate" and it manipulates all the data and displays it on the Results.java page. (the NEXT button at top was a test to see if I could even load the Results page, which no, clicking the NEXT button just crashes the app, and the calculate button is not even clickable)

[MainActivity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6t4V.jpg)

[MainActivity.java continued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVFvV.jpg)

Does anyone have any idea why my calculate button is not working on my app?
I am only allowed to post 2 links so if you need another picture let me know.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text, in the question itself. Include the [stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) from the crash, as well.

Answer (score 0):

your onButtonCalculate() doesn't call add

```
android:onClick="onButtonCalculate"
```

In your XML code

Comment: I had that but had tools:onClick="onButtonCalculate" ops. changed that

but now I'm getting this error:

Error while executing: am start -n "tigerterrors.sprint2app/tigerterrors.sprint2app.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=tigerterrors.sprint2app/.MainActivity }

Comment: Here is a picture of my error and my Manifest

https://i.gyazo.com/363ac243d7163c536128aea7239a07a8.png

Comment: any idea as to why I keep getting this error? @Harsh Singhal